# Returning after onclick action finish execution

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that checks if user properties are set. It displays the settings menu if they are not and settings button if they are. The problem is that when I submit settings (by either setting new ones or changing the old ones) I can't make the script to return to the main menu, i.e. to rerun the `MainFunction`. Can someone help me with that?

```
function MainFunction() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var api_key = userProperties.getProperty('api_key');
  var source = userProperties.getProperty('source');
  console.log(api_key);
  console.log(source);
  if (api_key == null || source == null || api_key.length < 2 || source.length < 2) {
    return f_change_settings();
  } else {
    return f_add_settings_button();
  }
}

function f_change_settings(s) {  
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var api_key = userProperties.getProperty('api_key');
  var source = userProperties.getProperty('source');

  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('notificationCallback');
  return CardService
  .newCardBuilder()
  .addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput().setFieldName('api_key').setTitle('api_key').setValue(api_key))
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput().setFieldName('source').setTitle('source').setValue(api_key))
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Submit').setOnClickAction(action))
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(' '))
  )
  .build();
}

function notificationCallback(a) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(a.formInput['source']);
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('api_key', a.formInput['api_key']);
  userProperties.setProperty('source', a.formInput['source']);
  CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
  .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
  .setText("Done"))
  .build();
//  MainFunction();
  return;
}

function f_add_settings_button() {  
  var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('f_change_settings');
  return CardService
  .newCardBuilder()
  .addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Settings').setOnClickAction(action))
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(' '))
  )
  .build();
}
```

I tried calling the `MainFunction` from the callback but not working (the commented line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just set `MainFunction` as your callback, instead of `notificationCallback`:

```js
var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('MainFunction');
```

And set the new user properties at the beginning of this function (only if there has previously been a form submission):

```js
function MainFunction(a) {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  if (a.formInput['api_key'] && a.formInput['source']) {
    userProperties.setProperty('api_key', a.formInput['api_key']);
    userProperties.setProperty('source', a.formInput['source']);
  }
  var api_key = userProperties.getProperty('api_key');
  var source = userProperties.getProperty('source');
  if (api_key == null || source == null || api_key.length < 2 || source.length < 2) {
    return f_change_settings();
  } else {
    return f_add_settings_button();
  }
}
```

Comment: Iamblichus you are genius :) 

i don't know why your code is giving error at
`if (a.formInput['api_key'] && a.formInput['source']) 
{`
but if i change this: 
`if (a.formInput['api_key'] && a.formInput['source']) { 
}` 
to this: `if (a) { if (a.formInput) {
 if (a.formInput['api_key'] && a.formInput['source']) {
 }
 }
 }`

 it works as expected! Thank you very much